# Browser intent and return to correct activity (close opened tab)

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, oauth-2.0

When implementing a custom account type in `AccountManager` in  Android I have the following problem for the sign in flow:

The sign in should happen through an OAuth provider. Therefore I have created a `SignInActivity` which launches a `WebView` and starts an OAuth flow. This works fine, when the callback is received to `my-custom-scheme://callback` the `WebView` detects it, receives the `code` querystring parameter and completes the flow. The disadvantage with using a `WebView` is that even though the user might already have an active session in the browser, this session is not used in the `WebView` so the user will have to login again in the `WebView`.

To solve this, I tried switching to using an `intent-filter` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="my-custom-scheme" android:path="callback"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Instead of opening a `WebView` in the `SignInActivity`, I then launch a browser intent and wait for the browser to hit `my-custom-scheme://callback`.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "http://oauth2provider/authorize");
startActivity(browserIntent);
finish();
```

In my `SignInActivity` I have the following code to handle the callback:

```
if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null && getString("my-custom-scheme").equals(intent.getData().getScheme())) {
    String code = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("code");
    // complete oauth flow
}
```

This works. But, **to the problem** (finally!):

1. If the user is not signed in, the browser intent will display the sign in page for the oauth provider. After the user has signed in, Chrome will redirect to my-custom-scheme://callback and `SignInActivity` will launch to handle the intent. As this activity is invisible, the browser will stay open on the sign in page, and to the user it will look like nothing happened. The browser never closes.
2. If the user is already signed in, the oauth provider will redirect directly to my-custom-scheme://callback. In this case, the browser **tab** is closed automatically but the browser itself remains open (with no tabs visible).

So my question is: is there anyway to make the browser behave differently after having redirected to my-custom-scheme://callback? Ideally, I would like it to simply close after having redirected to the callback, and to return to the previous activity in the activity stack (i.e. to the activity that started the `SignInActivity` from the beginning).

Answer (score 5):

I used the next approach to fix the same issue.

Let's assume we have `MainActivity` with `Sign In` button. **Instead** of starting browser directly clicking on that button I'm starting `SignInActivity` using `startActivityForResult` method. It's using for then I can handle result of login flow.

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class), requestCode);`

`SignInActivity` is responsible for:

- open browser with login page
- catch redirect to `custom-scheme://callback`
- finish login flow using token received from redirected url
- return result back to `MainActivity`

So, its `onCreate` method looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null && "custom-scheme".equals(intent.getData().getScheme())) {
        String code = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("code");
       // complete oauth flow
    } else {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "http://oauth2provider/authorize")
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Admit flags set into the browser intent.

This way if `SignInActivity` is opened from `MainActivity` it just opens login page in the browser and if it's opened catching redirect url it completes login flow sending appropriate request.

After you complete login flow sending the code to some endpoint in your callback method you should do the following:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
this.finish();
```

Naturally, you receive access_token from that endpoint. You can store it somewhere either here, in the success callback or return it back to the `MainActivity` to handle it there.

As layout for `SignInActivity` you can use just `ProgressBar` in the center of the page. It will appear during login flow completion after `SignInActivity` is opened caught redirect url (`custom-scheme://callback`).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <ProgressBar
       android:layout_width="48dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is declaration of `SignInActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".SignInActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTask"
          android:noHistory="true"
     >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
         <data android:scheme="custom-scheme" android:host="callback"/>
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: it is not help for me